# Does assert and uncaught exceptions generate a crash report?

Tags: iphone, ios, error-handling, assert, error-reporting

Will failed `assert` statements generate crash reports (with stack traces) that'll wind their way through iTunes Connect?

I'd like to know the same thing for `NSAssert` as well as uncaught C++/Obj-C exceptions.

Please note that I'm using assertions for internal consistency and logic errors, not for things like file errors.

If they don't generate error reports, is there a way to make them (with custom macros, exception handlers, etc)? It's important that I be able to obtain a stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, uncaught exceptions will generate a crash report - I'm looking at one from the iTunes Connect crash reporter right now! Basically, almost anything that causes your application to crash and save logs will send reports back to Apple.

*That said*, if you're worried about it you may want to implement your own handler for crash reporting, because a) only users who opt to share diagnostic information with Apple will send crash reports back to iTunes Connct, and b) there is no guarantee that even then a crash report will make it back to you for review.

You can either do this yourself using uncaught exception handlers, through an existing analytics package (Flurry supports this), or use an open source library which are of variable quality ([here's one I've found online](http://github.com/kaler/CrashKit) - I implement my own code for my reporting, so your mileage may vary!)

Comment: I experimented with assert and C++/Obj-C exceptions and looked at "Device Logs" in XCode's Organizer. I can confirm that they all indeed generate stack traces that let you pinpoint the source of the failure. However, the exception types and messages are not logged.

Comment: I may not have time to implement or use a crash handler. But it's nice to know that I can at least get iTunes Connect crash reports for all types of uncaught exceptions, without any additional programming effort on my part.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode will, by default, disable `NSAssert()` macros for release builds if you are using one of the standard Xcode templates. Alternately, you can disable them yourself by adding an `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS` flag to Other C++ Flags in your Build Settings.

Comment: Good to know. I had to edit the release mode build configuration so that assertions are not disabled.